# Increase vertical dimension simple form for - Text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a website where users can write their poetries. I created a simple form for where the user can write the title of the poetry, body of the poetry, and his name/nickname.
Since the poetries are generally vertically long (short phrases with a lot of new lines), I am trying to expand vertically the dimension of the field: ':body'.

My simple form for is:

```
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <%= form_for(poetry) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title, "Titolo"%>
        <%= f.text_field :title, as: :string, class: 'form-control'%>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body, "Poesia"%>
        <%= f.text_field :body, as: :text, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :author, "Autore" %>
        <%= f.text_field :author, as: :string, label: false, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <%= f.submit "Conferma",  class:"btn btn-secondary btn-lg" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add the following pieces of code, but they are not working.

```
:input_html => {:maxlength => 15, :size => 40}

:input_html => {:maxlength =>2,:style=> 'width: 20px'}

<%= f.text_field, :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to scope the `size` attribute under `:input_html`.  Rails documentation for [text_field](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field) has some examples, and [text_field_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag) shows the defined options available.

`<%= f.text_area :title, rows: 40 %>`

Conversely, if you are meaning to use simple_form you need to use `simple_form_for` instead of `form_for`.

`<%= f.text_field :message, input_html: {rows: 10} %>`

Comment: Thanks for this.  I added to my code the second snippet you wrote and change ':message' to ':body' (the name of that field).
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body, "Poesia"%>
        <%= f.text_field :body, input_html: {rows: 50}, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
But still the size of the "body" is not changing.

Comment: Did you change `form_for` to `simple_form_for`?

Comment: I tried both with simple_form_for (with input_html: {rows: 10}) and with form_for (with  rows: 40).

Comment: Did you leave the `as: :text` included? Is the HTML output `<textarea...` or `input[type=text]`? `f.input :body, as: :text...`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! This is my code now:
    `<%= form_for(poetry) do |f| %>


    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body, "Poesia"%>
    <%= f.text_field :body, :size => 100, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Conferma",  class:"btn btn-secondary btn-lg" %>
    <% end %>`

Comment: <%= text_area, :body, rows: 100 %>. That should make you a <textarea> tag.  I have it messed up in my answer. Sorry about that! Also, for textarea height you need to use rows not size. I updated my answer above.